# Responsive bootstrap rowspan-like reordering

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4 is it possible to go from

```
|   | b |   |
| a |---| c |
|   | d |   |

on xs to

|         | a |
|         |---|
|    b    | c |
|         |---|
|         | d |
```

on sm and up?

Been looking through the flex documentation and can't find a way to achieve both without hiding and revealing duplicate layout elements.

```
<div class="container pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-2 categories">
            a
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="mainPanel">
                b
            </div>
            <div class="colors">
                d
            </div>
            <div class="item"><< Select Item >></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 patterns">
            c
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This builds the first example, but nesting b and d within another div means they can't be reordered as I want.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Comment: Flexbox for 1-dimensional layouts, CSS-Grid for 2-dimensional layouts. Yours is the latter; you can't achieve it with flexbox alone.